# AS3: ERROR 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Stage and TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop, error-handling

So, I'm making a game and when I test my class into a file I get four errors of the same type '1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Stage and TextField'. I've imported everything, please take a look:

Game.as

```
package  {

import flash.display.Stage.*;
import flash.filter.GlowFilter.*;
import flash.text.TextField.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest.*;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod.*;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat.*;
import flash.net.URLVariables.*;


public class Game {

    public static const STATUS_MENU:int = 1;
    public static const STATUS_SURVIVAL:int = 2;
    public static const STATUS_MULTIPLAYER:int = 3;

    public static const GAME_RUN:int = 1;
    public static const GAME_PAUSE:int = 2;

    public static var palco:Stage;
    public static var profileName:Array; //Name, status, pass

    public function Game():void {
        trace("Class Game is online.");
    }

    public function transStage(sender:Stage):Stage {
        palco = sender;
        palco.align = StageAlign.BOTTOM_LEFT;
        palco.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
        palco.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        return(palco);
    }

    public function makeGlow(txt:TextField):void {
        var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(); 
        glow.color = 0xFFFFFF; 
        glow.alpha = 1; 
        glow.blurX = 4.5; 
        glow.blurY = 4.5; 
        glow.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;
        txt.filters = [glow];

    }

    public function removeGlow(txt:TextField):void {
        txt.filters = [];
    }

    public function setStatus(current:int):void {
        var request1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.url.com/");
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var vari:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        vari.Profile = profileArray[1];
        switch (current) {
            case 1:
            vari.Status = 1;
            profileArray[2] = 1;
            break;
            case 2:
            vari.Status = 2;
            profileArray[2] = 2;
            break;
            case 3:
            vari.Status = 3;
            profileArray[2] = 3;
            break;
        }
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        request1.data = vari;
        request1.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        loader.load(request1);
    }

    }
   }
```

And here's the fla test file:

```
import Game;

var manager:Game = new Game();
```

Also, if have any suggestions about the way I organize or the way I made this code please post here, because I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your imports are wrong.

```
//Change
import flash.display.Stage.*;
import flash.filter.GlowFilter.*;
import flash.text.TextField.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest.*;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod.*;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat.*;
import flash.net.URLVariables.*;


/ to
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.filter.GlowFilter;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
```

Answer (score 1):

.* means "load every class in that folder" but `flash.display.Stage` is already a class so you don't need the .*
Use either import `flash.display.Stage;` or `import flash.display.*;`
I suggest the second because you're likely to need more classes in flash.display
Same thing with import `flash.text.TextField;` and the others

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
```